# 'failed to identify file' while copying file between databases?

Tags: oracle

I want to copy Bfiles from db1 to db2.
I can not create Bfiles inside db2.
I have used DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER.get_file procedure in a db2 instance.

```
DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER.get_file(
   source_directory_object      => 'db1_dir',
   source_file_name             => 'test.html',
   source_database        =>  'db2_to_db1',
   destination_directory_object => 'db2_dir',
   destination_file_name        => 'test.html');
END;
/
```

Also, I have tried DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER.put_file procedure in a db1 instance.

```
DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER.put_file(
   source_directory_object      => 'db1_dir',
   source_file_name             => 'test.html',
   destination_directory_object => 'db2_dir',
   destination_file_name        => 'test.html');
   destination_database        =>  'db1_to_db2',
END;
/
```

But both function issue a same error.

```
ORA-19505: failed to identify file "/rdsdbdata/userdirs/05/test.html"
ORA-27046: file size is not a multiple of logical block size
Additional information: 1
ORA-02063: preceding 3 lines from db1_to_db2/db2_to_db1
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER", line 37
ORA-06512: at "SYS.DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER", line 132
ORA-06512: at line 2
19505. 00000 -  "failed to identify file \"%s\""
*Cause:    call to identify the file returned an error
*Action:   check additional messages, and check if the file exists.
```

Comment: According to this (https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=file-transfer) dbms_file_transfer is for database files only.

Comment: So why can't you create BFILE objects in your second database?  That's the problem you need to solve. Copying OS files is only part of the BFILE task.

Answer (score 0):

APC is correct, as stated in Oracle [`DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E18283_01/appdev.112/e16760/d_ftran.htm#i998903) help:

> To run this procedure successfully, the current user must have the following privileges:

> READ privilege on the directory object specified in the source_directory_object parameter 
> **WRITE privilege on directory object specified in the destination_directory_object parameter**

It seems you are missing the last point, check your WRITE permissions for the db2.

DBMS_FILE_TRANSFER can copy any file via `COPY_FILE` procedure, not only database ones. This restriction Rene says about, is true only for ASM destinations.